# Jboss jsp issue <> operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

I have jboss eap 6.2.2 running on my server with JDK 7. In my web application I have a jsp that uses jdk7 diamond operator

```
Map<String, String> menuItems = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

I get an error on accessing this jsp:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: JBWEB004062: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
JBWEB004060: An error occurred at line: 5 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/pagecomponents/menu.jsp
'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
```

Is there a default source compatibility that jboss uses, if yes is there a way to change it?

Comment: Are you seeing this within Eclipse?

Comment: I read somewhere that the default JDK version for JBoss 7 for compiling JSPs is 1.5. Assuming that is correct, JBoss 6.2.2 is unlikely to be higher than that. So chances are you need to setup a target JDK in your configuration.

Comment: @radimpe I see, going through the jboss documentation to check how to change it. Surprisingly no one seems to have come across this issue - didn't get any good results from google :(

Comment: @Disco3 this is while accessing the jsp (runtime), not in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I have tested this on EAP 6.1.0, but believe it should be the same on 6.2.2.

JSP compilation is performed by the web subsystem under JBoss EAP 6.

If you look at the schema for "jboss:domain:web:1.4" you can see that the default value for the compiler is 1.5, https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/master/build/src/main/resources/docs/schema/jboss-as-web_1_4.xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="jsp-configurationType">
      ...
      <xs:attribute name="scratch-dir" />
      <xs:attribute name="source-vm" default="1.5" />
      <xs:attribute name="target-vm" default="1.5" />
```

You can change this in your standalone-full.xml. My local copy looks like:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.4" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <configuration>
    <jsp-configuration source-vm="1.7" target-vm="1.7"/>
    ...
```

There is an argument that if you should limit your scriptlet code as much as possible, so it maybe better to move your code out of the JSP

Comment: Yes, found the reference in jboss docs: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/jsp.html About the scriptlet - I realize that, but this is an exception case.